# Iphone app. How many were downkoaded

Tags: iphone, app-store, download

I wrote an iphone app and was just released.curious to See how many people downloaded it. It is a free app. How do i find out how many people downloaded my app.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from your Apple Developer account, use iTunes Connect to get stats on your app downloads.  You can also use third party services like [AppFigures](http://www.appfigures.com/) to get better stats.

Comment: Where in itune connect do you see this?  I am having a hard time locating it.  Thanks

Comment: Check out the iTunes Connect Mobile app for iPhone or iPad. I prefer it to the actual web portal because the graphs are much fancier. You can even break the graphs out by app if you have more than one, which is something the web site can't do for some dumb reason.

Comment: Look under "Sales and Trends".  If your app has just been listed it may take a few days for the stats to update.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the statistics will be available in iTunes Connect only after a week or so. Try Appannie (appannie.com) for better reports.